# Why is the publication date shown next to the view count?

Tags: youtube

When I have signed into the YouTube with my Google account, the date is shown next to the view count. But when I am not signed in, it is showing below the channel's name.

Why is it so? And how can I make it go back to the original location for my account?

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I now know why the ***publication date stopped showing*** for me (started a few days ago). At high zoom levels (and logged in), there isn't enough space for the publication date. Zooming out displays the publication date. (It shows that [TechLead no longer works at Google](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ODaq-JEiIKg) (he worked on the YouTube client).)

Comment: I think this changed a few days ago (see my other comment), primo 2019-09.

Comment: I don't understand your TechLead part of the comment, but you mean that this is happening to others, too. I was using an extension that moved the description on the right panel, which narrows the width, and that caused the date not to be shown.This is an annoying change. If there is no option to change this, I think I will create an extension to move the position, myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably an experiment, so the same thing as [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/135268/145802) applies:

There sometimes are workarounds for this, though unfortunately YouTube doesn't have any easy opt-out feature. You can try some of these however:

- Clear cookies. Often, these experiments are cookie-based (with the `VISITOR_INFO1_LIVE` cookie being the main culprit), though yours might be account-based instead.
- Use the old design. You can switch to it with the [`disable_polymer`](https://www.youtube.com/?disable_polymer=1) URL parameter, or using an extension/userstyle to emulate it.
- Use a userstyle. There are [quite a few available](https://userstyles.org/styles/browse/youtube), though they tend to break whenever YouTube updates something (like they did with your thumbnails). Knowing a bit of CSS to fix things yourself helps here.
- Use a different browser and/or resize the browser. This will definitely have a different cookie set, plus even account-based experiments sometimes are set out to work in one browser only (which usually is Chrome), or on only one type of screen size or aspect ratio.